# GAE TaskQueue hitting Endpoints API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, task-queue

I have an endpoint api named "gameApi"

I have an api called:

`@ApiMethod(name = "startNewRound", path = "evaluateRound", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)`

I'm trying to run the following task queue:

`queue.add(
    ofy().getTransaction(),
    TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/_ah/api/gameApi/v1/evaluateRound")
        .param("gameId", gameId.toString())
        .method(TaskOptions.Method.POST)
        .countdownMillis(5000));`

I'm getting a 404 in the logs:

> 0.1.0.2 - - [14/Nov/2014:14:58:28 -0800] "POST /_ah/api/gameApi/v1/evaluateRound HTTP/1.1" 404 234 "https://some-appspot-123.appspot.com/_ah/spi/com.appspot.some_appspot_123.spi.GameAPI.playCard" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "some-appspot-123.appspot.com" ms=8 cpu_ms=21 cpm_usd=0.000026 queue_name=default task_name=62689306220576549071 instance=00c61b117c54ec2fb802c51c19fe26523ec51854 app_engine_release=1.9.16

It looks like it's hitting the HTTP and not the HTTPS page.  Is there a way I can force it to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

In endpoints, `HTTP 404` corresponds to `com.google.api.server.spi.response.NotFoundException`.

Is it possible that the method has not been defined in the API class, or that it doesn't have [a correct annotation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apimethod_method-scoped_annotations)?

Also, it doesn't seem like it's hitting http, the trace clearly shows https as the protocol. I think it's only possible to use http on localhost.

Comment: I was able to hit it using the javascript api